# Show connected ids of clients in a Gridview or a listbox winform using SIgnalR

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, signalr

I have a hub class which overrides the `OnConnected` method...

```
public override Task OnConnected()
{
    UserHandler.ConnectedIds.Add(Context.ConnectionId);
    string RemoteIpAddress = Context.Request.GetRemoteIpAddress();
    return base.OnConnected();
}
```

...and a static class is which keeps the count of connected clients and their connection ids.

```
public static class UserHandler
{
    public static List<string> ConnectedIds = new List<string>();
}
```

I also have a form that is intended to show all the connected clients with their ids...

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IHubContext hubContext = lobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<MyHub>();
    UserHandler.ConnectedIds = hubContext.Clients.All.ConnectionId;
    listBox1.Items.Add(UserHandler.ConnectedIds);
}
```

What I want to achieve...

I want to show the connected clients with their ids - and once it completes then I will make such login, so that if I want to chat with a specific client, I will just click on that client's id shown in a grid and select send message.

Comment: Some more informations would be good. What's the current problem? Are the connected clients displayed or not? If not: did you get an exception?

Comment: while debugging i get the the connection ids on override method of hubclass, the problem is how to take all those connection ids to the form1 gridview

Comment: @MightyBadaboom see the button2_click on form1.
i tried using this but error is on 

UserHandler.ConnectedIds = hubContext.Clients.All.ConnectionId;

which says 

'Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs.ClientProxy' does not contain a definition for 'ConnectionId'

Comment: @MightyBadaboom ok wait let me check !

Comment: @MightyBadaboom same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to remove the first and second line in your button2_Click method. You already added the connectionIds to your UserHandler instance in your overridden OnConnected method.

//edit
I have not changed anything at your code. I don't know how you still get an error.
[image: Test]

//edit 
You already have the connectionIds in your list? Why not using them? This will add the connectionIds to your datagrid. If you need more information like the username you could replace ConnectedIds in your UserHandler with a class with two properties username and connectionId.

```
if (UserHandler.ConnectedIds.Count != 0)
{
    foreach(var connectionId in UserHandler.ConnectedIds)
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(connectionId);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just to be sure.
In your button2_Click method is only the third line left and when you click button2 you get the error: 'Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs.ClientProxy' does not contain a definition for 'ConnectionId'?

Comment: Your OnConnected method works like expected and the connectionIds will be added? What's the content of the UserHandler.ConnectedIds in the button2_click method?

Comment: @yes my Onconnected method works fine, 

 this line UserHandler.ConnectedIds.Add(Context.ConnectionId);  gets the connection ids and on button2_Click 

this line does nothing 
UserHandler.ConnectedIds = hubContext.Clients.All.ConnectionId;

Comment: Just to be sure: you still get an error when your button2_Click method is like
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listBox1.Items.Add(UserHandler.ConnectedIds);
}

Comment: I can't help you anymore without having the sourcecode because I can not retrace your problem.

Comment: Zip your solution, google 'upload files', upload the zip file and post the link would be one way ;)

Comment: See my changed answer with an example picture. I got the correct number of connected clients. Don't know where the problem is.

Comment: i know it is working fine in respect to get the number of clients, but i have not mentioned it by mistake in my post that i need to show the "Connection ids" of connected cients in gridview and their username as well. so that afterwords if i need to send a message to the specific client in my gridview just i need to click on that cell which has the username and connection id of that client and will send message.

for this i need to show them in the grid first, that is the current task my brother

Comment: See my changed answer. You alread sent messages via Signal R. So I guess this won't be a problem.